# How to put analytics code in one place in mobile platform?

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics, analytics

Right now when I am using any analytics to track events in my app I add small pieces of code on action of button or after viewing one screen. Due to this my analytics logic or codes have spread in multiple places which make hard to make any changes.
All I do is put some comment before analytics code. So I was thinking if there is any way put all my analytics codes and logics to one place rather then multiple places in app.

PS:- iOS specific solution will be more helpful for me.

Comment: try this http://www.androidhive.info/2015/08/android-integrating-google-analytics-v4/

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a helper class (something like AnalyticsUtil.java) which will contain the actual analytics calls inside some convenience methods. Now you can just call these methods in places you need to record analytics data.

This approach has the additional benefit that you can always plug in multiple analytics sources in the helper class without needing to change the rest of the project.